# Is there a better alternative to Eclipse to program android applications?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA for Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964168/benefits-of-switching-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea-for-android-development)

Well I have been using Eclipse and as noted by one of the person's that answered my questions a while back, Eclipse is really 'goofy'. It makes it hard to code sometimes and you have to clean and build multiple times and on several occassions restart Eclipse altogether.

So I am thinking is there a better IDE you can program android applications on that are more stable than Eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

I've recently been using [IntelliJ IDEA 12 (Community Edition)](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) under Mac and Linux and have found it to be excellent.

*Although this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964168/benefits-of-switching-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea-for-android-development) and so will probably be closed.*

I asked the question before and there wasn't enough in IDEA for me to make the change, but since it now includes an Android UI Designer, there is enough in it.  All that's missing now is a `AndroidManifest.xml` editor...